# Not being able to store a variant in a pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, wrapper, variant

My groupmate and I are doing a school assignment and we are having some trouble trying to save a value.
I am 100% aware that some of the things done in the code is not the normal way of doing, and that there are better ways, but part of the assignment is to use the concepts taught in class.

Problem:

I have a Train class which I would like to assign to a platform, such that I know if there is a train on the platform.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Train
{
public:
    //Some constructors, getters and other stuff 
private:
    std::string reg_nr_;
}
```

Because the Train is a template there are different template argument classes so it is possible to give it a type

```cpp
struct IC3{};

struct IC4{};
```

To instantiate a Train it is done in main in the following way, as is the way it is intended to be used.

```cpp
Train<IC3> tester_train("testing_train");
Train<IC4> some_other_tester_train("some_other_tester_train");

Platform pl;
pl.train_arriving(tester_train);
pl.train_leaving(tester_train);
pl.train_arriving(some_other_tester_train);
```

```cpp
class Platform
{
public:
    using Trains = std::variant<TrainWrapper<Train<Arriva>>, TrainWrapper<Train<IC3>>, TrainWrapper<Train<IC4>>>;

    template<typename U>
    void train_arriving(U& t)
    {
        train_ = TrainWrapper<U>{ u };
    }

    void train_leaving()
    {
        train_ = ???????; //Should be set to nothing
    }
private:
    Trains train_;
}
```

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct TrainWrapper
{
    T& t;
};
```

Now for the real part of the problem.
I have a Train template class which takes an argument and transform the Train in different types which are not compatible. This presents a problem of being able to pass these different train types into the platform and saving them.
To solve the problem of different passing in different types a std::variant has been used. This presented a new problem of not being able to retrieve the data easily, which is why the TrainWrapper is used, such that the Train is stored in a common type.

Tinkering around with the variant (and finally asking our teacher) my groupmate and I arrived `Trains` expression seen in Platform. We know for a fact (using a local variable) that we are able to save a TrainWrapper in a Trains object. Our problem however is that we would like to be able to change the Train on the Platform. We therefore thought a pointer would be the way forward, but doing this we run into conversion errors like: `Error    C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'TrainWrapper<Train<Arriva>>' to 'Platform::Trains *'`. We have tried a bunch of different pointer variations, but it is always the same conversion error.

So our question more or less is: How are we able to save Train on the platform so we are able to remove it again?

Comment: Is there any reason why you avoid dynamic polymorphism? That is, to have a single base class for all the trains and derive particular types of trains (`IC3`, `IC4`, etc.) from it?

Comment: As the number of train classes will raise, you get for each template a new instance which will grow your binary very fast without any need. It looks much cleaner, if you have a base class which represents any kind of train and provide the interface which can be used by your "platform". Having fully unrelated classes and use the std::visit may be a solution, but comes with the cost of a much bigger binary. And std::visit may be much slower as vtable access, as sometimes e.g. gcc generates jump tables for std::visible in run time.

Comment: I know that this problem probably not would have existed if we used polymorphism. Unfortunately that has not really been a focus in this course (although it has been covered plenty by earlier courses), but rather there has been a focus on templates and how it possible to achieve certain things during compile time. 
So the reason for doing it this way is simply to show an understanding for the concepts taught in the course. In our project report we are allowed to write "We know this is bad for this and this reason", so this being a bad solution is not a problem

Comment: What is `TrainWrapper`?  Where does `u` come from?  How can you have two `train_arriving` methods with identical signatures?

Comment: @Eljay The `TrainWrapper`is just supposed to wrap our `Train` obejcts to make it easier to use `std::visit`. `U` is just supposed to be our argument. I blindly admit that we not entirely sure about the the parameter should be `U` or something like `Train<U>` or something else.
The two identical `train_arriving` was a type. One was supposed to be a `train_leaving`. That has been fixed in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) to signal empty:

```
class Platform
{
public:
    using Trains = std::variant<std::monostate,
                                TrainWrapper<Train<Arriva>>,
                                TrainWrapper<Train<IC3>>,
                                TrainWrapper<Train<IC4>>>;

    template<typename U>
    void train_arriving(U& t)
    {
        train_ = TrainWrapper<U>{ u };
    }

    template<typename U>
    void train_leaving(U& )
    {
        train_ = std::monostate{};
    }
private:
    Trains train_;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5d218782ba4b705)

Comment: This seems like the solution. However when I try it out I get the following error, which I do not quite understand: 
Error C2280 'std::variant<std::monostate,TrainWrapper<Train<Arriva>>,TrainWrapper<Train<IC3>>,TrainWrapper<Train<IC4>>> &std::variant<std::monostate,TrainWrapper<Train<Arriva>>,TrainWrapper<Train<IC3>>,TrainWrapper<Train<IC4>>>::operator =(const std::variant<std::monostate,TrainWrapper<Train<Arriva>>,TrainWrapper<Train<IC3>>,TrainWrapper<Train<IC4>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: @FrederikAndersen • change TrainWrapper from having a `T& t;` to `std::reference_wrapper<T> t;` and `#include <functional>`.  Or just use `std::reference_wrapper` in the `std::variant` directly and get rid of `TrainWrapper`.

Comment: Your issue is that `TrainWrapper` is not assignable. Demo added.

Comment: @Eljay That worked. Changing to `std::reference_wrapper<T>` in combination with the `std::monostate` solved our problem. We have just run our code verified that everything works as it is supposed to. Thank you @Jarod42 and @Eljay